# Use Arduino programmer modes to upload code on virtual COM port

Tags: com, arduino, virtual, bootloader

This question is related to [Upload Arduino code on virtual serial port through Arduino IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15785087/upload-arduino-code-on-virtual-serial-port-through-arduino-ide). The main problem is being able to upload code onto virtual COM port instead of using Arduino so I could take the binary code output and use it in some other application. The problem with that is that the process of uploading is also related to the bootloader on the Arduino and that's why the upload process never reaches 100%. The suggested solution was either to implement a bootloader in my application or use something that is already out there.

My question now is can I make use of the different programmer modes in the Arduino IDE to sort of by-pass the bootloader so the upload process can reach 100% and the code would actually reach the virtual COM port?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your Virtual Serial Port driver is getting stuck on some timeouts or buffers. The IDE calls avrdude with a specific protocol to match with what is built into the Arduino's bootloader, loaded on the AVR. There are other bootloader (in fact many, too many to mention), some of which may have different timing and such, but to use them would basically no longer be Arduino. to see the possibilities .\avrdude.exe -c.

If you are just trying to get a dump of what is going over the Serial port. I have used [Virtual Serial Ports Emulator](http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html) . It is very versatile in that its modular, allowing you to build up what you want.

Also, as mentioned from the other threads about this, note the data over the serial port is formated ontop of the [STK500 protocol](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2591.pdf). You also mention in other thread that you don't want to use another tool to get the data. Whereas in order to use another protocol you would need to change the source compiler.java and rebuild the project as to call avrdude with the new protocol. So you might as well just get it with another tool. see below this will tie back in.

you can get the raw binary, from what is being fed to avrdude. Where as it may not be initially obvious. As avrdude get ELF not BIN. The Arduino IDE contains all of avr-gcc and its tools. Where avr-objcopy located in .\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr\bin can convert the IDE's output that is funneled into avrdude, to the binary you likely desire. No need for scoping the serial port stream.

To do this by hand, You need to locate IDE's temp working directory, by enabling the IDE's verbose compile prints. And also likely put avr-objcopy in your path. then simply call it as in the below example, substituting your sketch's filename, in place of mine.

```
C:\Users\mflaga\AppData\Local\Temp\build6135656488044319492.tmp>avr-objcopy -I ihex FilePlayer.cpp.hex -O binary FilePlayer.cpp.bin
```

Where as you could replace avrdude.exe with a batchfile that calls both avrdude and avr-objcopy to automat

Comment: well I do not want to do it manually as my program will take the .elf and use it to simulate the Arduino so for my program to have a decent UI I can't ask the user to copy paste where he saved the sketch. So I need the code to be uploaded onto the Arduino and that the upload progress in the IDE would not freeze when it reaches 90% cause of the bootloader.